# node require resolves to original extension after clearing cache and deleting file

Tags: node.js, require

My code is executing `const cfg = require('./config')` so that either `config.js` or `config.json` will be read. In general this works fine. The problem I'm running into is during testing.

The testing code iterates on these steps:

- clear the require cache for `require.resolve('./config.json')`
- write `config.json` with data to be tested
- test the code containing `const cfg = require('./config')`

Everything above works fine. The problem comes when the test tries to verify that `config.js` works as well.

- clear the require cache for `require.resolve('./config.json')`
- delete `config.json`
- write `config.js`
- test the code containing `const cfg = require('./config')`

The attempt to read `config.js` via `require('./config')` fails because `require.resolve('./config')` still resolves to the `.json` file which no longer exists.

The behavior could be explained by the directory being cached somewhere so that writing `config.js` is not reflected in node's require search. But that's just a guess.

Reversing the order of the tests so that the `.js` tests are performed first followed by the `.json` tests results in the same problem but reversed.

The behavior is the same on node versions 6+; I haven't tested earlier versions.

How can node's require be made to return the export of the `.js` file in this scenario?

The following illustrates the problem. By specifying the extension in the require statement (change `const withExt = false` to `true`) it succeeds.

```
'use strict'

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const fs = require('fs');

const fullConfigName = `${process.cwd()}/xyzzy`;

function cleanup (ext) {
  // remove any files created with the default names
  try {fs.unlinkSync(`${fullConfigName}.${ext}`)} catch (e) {
    console.log(`failed to cleanup ${ext}`, e.code || e.message);
  }
  // clear the require cache
  delete require.cache[`${fullConfigName}.${ext}`];
}


function writeFile (extension) {
  let config;
  if (extension === 'json') {
    config = JSON.stringify({some: 'i was json'}) + '\n';
  } else {
    config = 'module.exports = {someSetting: "i was a module"}\n'
  }
  fs.writeFileSync(`${fullConfigName}.${extension}`, config, 'utf8');
}

function main () {
  cleanup('js');
  cleanup('json');

  //const configName = fullConfigName;
  const configName = './xyzzy';
  const withExt = false;

  const exts = false ? ['json', 'js'] : ['js', 'json'];

  exts.forEach(ext => {
    const extPart = withExt ? `.${ext}` : '';

    console.log(`writing ${configName}.${ext}`);
    writeFile(ext);

    const fileToRequire = `${configName}${extPart}`;
    console.log(`requiring ${fileToRequire}`);

    const resolved = require.resolve(fileToRequire);
    console.log(`require.resolve result ${resolved}`);
    try {
      const contents = require(`${fileToRequire}`);
      console.log('contents', contents);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('require failed', e.code || e.message);
    }

    console.log(module.children.map(c => {
      return {
        id: c.id,
        exports: c.exports,
        filename: c.filename,
        loaded: c.loaded,
      }
    }));
    const cache = Object.keys(require.cache).filter(k => true || k.startsWith(fullConfigName));
    console.log('cache:', cache);

    console.log(`${ext} - cleanup`);
    cleanup(ext);
  })
}

main ()
```

Comment: Simple question, why do you need this? Will there be a switch from config.js to config.json in your app? If so why not use the full url with the extension in the require?

Comment: I'm testing a configuration module that will allow the end-user to supply either a .json file or a .js module. The configuration module doesn't have control over which the user will supply.

To your point - if test specifies the extension it succeeds. I'll add the simple test program I'm using.

Comment: And it's probably obvious but the only reason I really need it is for my own testing. The end-user won't be able to change the extension and ask to reread the config.